# Having trouble with implicit conversion in scala

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, json4s

Having this code

```
case class Workspace(ident: Long, name: String)
case class Project(ident: Long, name: String)

implicit def workspaceJSON: JSONR[Workspace] = new JSONR[Workspace] {
  def read(json: JValue) =
    Workspace.applyJSON(field[Long]("id"), field[String]("name"))(json)
}

implicit def projectJSON: JSONR[Project] = new JSONR[Project] {
  def read(json: JValue) =
    Project.applyJSON(field[Long]("id"), field[String]("name"))(json)
}

def parseEnt[T: JSONR](json: JValue): Either[String, T] =
  fromJSON[T](json).toEither.left.map{ _.toString }

def fetchProjects(ws: Workspace): Either[String, Project] = {
  parseEnt(parse("some text"))
}
```

Which fails to compile on `parseEnt(parse("some text"))` with

```
ambiguous implicit values:  both method taskJSON in class Fetcher of type =>
Fetcher.this.JSONR[types.Task]  and method workspaceJSON in class Fetcher of type =>
Fetcher.this.JSONR[Fetcher.this.Workspace]  match expected type Fetcher.this.JSONR[T]
```

Is there a way to assure scala, that in this case I want type variable `T` to be a `Project` and choose `projectJSON` function to parse it? Or if I'm doing it wrong, then how do it in right way?

Comment: How about if you explicitly say what you expect to parse? parseEnt[Project](parse("some text"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is trying to automatically infer the type `T`, which must be something that it can be produced starting from a `String` (more or less, but details an unimportant here)

Unfortunately it can't succeed, since you're providing multiple implicit conversions going from `String` to `Project` and `Workspace`. The simple solution is to explicitly indicate the type you're trying to produce:

```
parseEnt[Project](parse("some text"))
```

This pattern is fairly common with serialization type classes, where you are mapping multiple specific types to a generic one (`String` in this case).

Comment: I understand that compiler is ambiguous about which instance to use, but it look strange to me that it can't infere type from type of function `fetchProjects`, I thought it's pretty clear that in this case `T` should be `Project`. Seems I have to read more about type inference and implicits in scala.