# Expected type and polymorphic function with implicit parameters confuses type inference?

Tags: scala, implicit

This question was inspired by [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841924/having-trouble-with-implicit-conversion-in-scala).  In the example below, why does the combination of using the expected type of an expression along with implicit parameters cause the type inferencer to decide that the type parameter for the function doesn't constrain the implicit argument?  (If that's what actually happens here.)

```
case class ThingA(name: String)
case class ThingB(name: String)

class ThingClass[T]

implicit val thingClassA = new ThingClass[ThingA]
implicit val thingClassB = new ThingClass[ThingB]

def find[T](): Option[T] = None
def findWithContextBound[T: ThingClass](): Option[T] = None

val typeApplicationFind = find[ThingA]()
val typeApplicationFindWithContextBound = findWithContextBound[ThingA]()
val expectedTypeFind: Option[ThingA] = find()
val expectedTypeFindWithContextBound: Option[ThingA] = findWithContextBound()
```

Only the last expression is ambiguous, even though the expected type ought to constrain the type parameter for findWithContextBound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implicit resolution happens before type parameters are inferred. In you last line the type parameter is still an unresolved `T` when the compiler searches for the implicit `ThingClass`, and as a result both `thingClassA` and `thingClassB` are acceptable, so the compiler fails with the ambiguous implicit values error.

Why does Scala work this way? It allows the type parameters, and  hence the return type, to be determined by what implicits are available. One use of this is mapping `BitSet`:

```
import collection.immutable.BitSet
val bitSet = BitSet(1, 2)
// another BitSet:
val newBitSet = bitSet.map(_ + 1)
// BitSet can't hold String, so this is a SortedSet:
val notABitSet = bitSet.map(_.toString)
```

A `BitSet` can only hold `Int` instances. `BitSet.map` takes an implicit `CanBuildFrom` that indicates whether a particular result collection can be built from the starting collection while also containing the result of the map. There is a `CanBuildFrom` that allows mapping to another `BitSet` when the return type of the `map` function is `Int`, and there is a more general implicit that creates a `SortedSet` regardless of the return type. The first is chosen preferentially, but the compiler will fall back to the second when it needs to.